# Lightning force:inputField doesn't render correctly in table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, lightning, lightning-design-system

I'm trying to use force:inputField component for lookup fields in a lightning component. But event though lookup field shows up correct, it does not render correct in an html table. My html component is below. Why might be the problem?

[image]

```
<aura:component controller="AccountApexController">
    <aura:attribute name="myAcc" type="Account" default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }" />
    <div>
            <table class="slds-table" width="100%">

                    <tr>
                        <td><force:inputField aura:id="myAcc" value="{!v.myAccount.TestField__c}" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. It was lightning design system's `slds-table` tag. When I removed it input field rendered just fine.